# Make Next, Previous Link for Tabs

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery tab, and this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });
});​
```

how i can get next and Previous links for tabs?

This is my HTML Code:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <a href="#tab1">Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab2">Tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab3">Tab3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">Content 1</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">Content 2</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">Content 3</div>
</div>​
```

Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

Comment: Can you post your html snippet?

Comment: Oh god! too many errors from this site! i cant even post easy post! lol i added HTML code

Comment: I don't see any errors on SO. You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: i added html code in my post, what u need or what u mean?! what should i do now :D

Comment: I have edit the question and formatted properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick draft for a "Next" link:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    var activeTab = $('.tab_container div.tab_content:visible');
    var nextTab = activeTab.next();
    if(nextTab.length) {
        activeTab.hide();
        nextTab.show();
    }
});
```

For a "Previous" link, just change `next()` with `prev()` (and change also the `$('#next')` accordingly)

Comment: Add `<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>` to your HTML, it's working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Un8z3/1/)

Comment: oh thank u, its working now! but i dont know why is not work in my template!

Answer (score 0):

Refer the **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/fZKJ3/)**

I have applied CSS classes extra to your JQuery and HTML as follows:-

```
ul.tab li {
    display: none;
}
.active {
    display: block;
}
```

​
It seems working fine. Check it out once again.

Comment: im sorry, but i have a full codes for this tab. i have CSS, HTML and jQuery code, i just need Next and Previous links like sliders, i hope u undrstand me!